# Why can't I fix my TinkerTool to 100%?

Tags: glitch-2011

I have Tinkering III, but every time I try to repair it, it only goes up to 99%. Because of this I cannot complete "Tinker with your Tools" quest. How do I repair it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a Tinkertool to repair a tool (even itself) causes wear to it.  When repairing itself, this wear is applied *after* the repair, effectively capping the tool's wear at 99%.

The only way to repair a Tinkertool to 100% (say, for the quest) is to drag it onto a [second Tinkertool](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Tinker_With_Your_Tool%28s%29#Hints).

Comment: Be warned: even if you have a second tinkertool in your inventory, the Repair action will repair the tinkertool using itself. To correctly repair the tool to 100% you need to drag one tool on the other.

Comment: @Merus — Excellent distinction; I've updated my answer.